# How can I add a new property to an instance of an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, object-literal

Is it possible to add a new property to an anonymous type instance after it has been initialized? I want to do something like the following:

```
// Initialize new object to hold subset of information about each transaction.
var transactionJson = new {};

transactionJson[transaction.Id] = new {
     Status = transactionList.StatusProperty,
     Completed = transactionList.Completed,
     First = transactionList.First
};
```

Comment: That's not an object literal; it's an anonymous type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's inherently impossible.
Anonymous types are *immutable*, and are type-safe.

You should use a dictionary or a `DynamicObject`.

Comment: That's the problem with emulating the functionality of dynamic languages without being a dynamic language... just confuses people who expect it to work like everything else! :D

Comment: @SLaks: Not sure, will go ahead and try a DynamicObject today and let you know if it worked. Will try to remember to check which JSON serializer it is as well.